# converting list<int> to int[]

Tags: c#

Is there builtin method that would do this or do I always have to manually create a new array and then fill it up with a foreach loop

Comment: Why? The only valid reasons I can see you'd need to do this is to use API methods that require array arguments.  If that's your problem so be it, but otherwise just leave it as a list.

Comment: that was exactly the reason :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
list.ToArray()
```

Comment: lol, there's a minimum number of characters for comments, but not for answers ?

Comment: I think there is a minimum for answers too but this is longer than minimum.

Comment: Wooohhhh... Short and simple

Answer (score 11):

```
List<int> list = ...
...
int[] array = list.ToArray();
```

You can also use the CopyTo method :

```
int[] array = new int[list.Count];
list.CopyTo(array);
```

Comment: `List<T>` in .NET 2.0 has `ToArray`. `List<T>.ToArray` will not call the `Enumerable.ToArray` extension method.

Comment: Good point... I was indeed thinking about the extension method. I'll fix it